# Unable to export user and emplyeeid from ldap group

Tags: powershell, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to export user and employeeid from LDAP.
All the users are in a group that I extracted using the code bellow.
I also put them in a csv file.

How can I retrieve employeeid for each user ? Changing this query or creating a new one and using the csv file.

```
$groups = @()
$groups = 'CONBR-MES-DEV-USERS'
Write-Host 'Group_Name','Member'
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    $members = @()
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Server la.jnj.com -Identity $group 
    foreach ($member in $members)
        {
            Write-Host $member.SamAccountName 


        }
}
```

I want something like
userA   123456
userB   987654
and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `employeeID` attribute is not included in the default attribute set. One way you can fix this is to use `Get-ADObject` inside the loop and include the attribute. Example:

```
foreach ( $group in $groups ) {
  $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Server la.jnj.com -Identity $group 
  foreach ( $member in $members ) {
    $groupMember = $member | Get-ADObject -Properties employeeID,sAMAccountName
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      "Name"       = $groupMember.sAMAccountName
      "employeeID" = $groupMember.employeeID
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot.  I just did a little change since 
"Name"       = $groupMember.sAMAccountName 

didnt return anything. I used 

"Name"       = $Member.sAMAccountName

Comment: I forgot that `sAMAccountName` is not a default property with `Get-ADObject`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be performed without looping using a [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) filter similar to:
    (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=yourgorupname,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=net)

and returning attributes: "sAMAccountName" "employeeID"

-jim